# How to use special characters in a query

Tags: javascript, html, special-characters

When I try to search something like C&A the only query I get in Google is C...
How can I make this JavaScript convert special characters?

```
    function search_google()
{
    window.location = "http://www.google.be/search?q=" + document.google.search.value;
}
```

Comment: Please make your code into a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

```
function search_google()
{
    window.location = "http://www.google.be/search?q=" + encodeURIComponent(document.google.search.value);
}
```